# Breaking a 'Many' - Time Pad

Tags: attack, ciphertext-only-attack

I'm working on a problem, where given 12 ciphertexts, I'm trying to decode the 12th and find out the key. I've implemented a crib dragging attack, where the crib is a purely guessed word (not known/given), I'm sturggling to actually build the key based on the output, as it seems to be all gibberish...

````
# ciphertexts were encoded to hex and then encrypted with the key
ciphertexts=[]
ciphertexts.append('152cf42dfb2f80fcd02bebeeff3741f679d957eaee3bdfeeebd07269fe8116de01f371f6d1d3c7ae334b5dff0ca3afd5a2c00186263728c0a48b9d40')
ciphertexts.append('4720f37eac2f9cef993aebedfc7708e7759c00eef52087eeeedb7a20f09d42cf1bea3dfb93d3daa8320e4ff452efa398f4c453902b2734c7b1c48249')
ciphertexts.append('0226e92de539d2f89c3fe5fafc7b5afa7a9154a2ba7fd3acffca362afb9a40cc1caa3de5959c8eb43f414dfc48f7e7c7bcc00196263f238da0818349')
ciphertexts.append('122aef2de52483ec992df0f6eb3e08f2739d00eaf72392bae3db782af2d916c417a67bf3899bcbb2775a50f455e4afc0f4cc55c421373594e2909e0c')
ciphertexts.append('173be87be92edeb99827f3e6f93e5abf3d8a45ede93a91a2f39e7f27b7815ec01da66ef19496c0a3320218f955f7e7dabbd1019736342089a18d9442')
ciphertexts.append('082fa779fe2f97ead026e1e2fd7b45f63d9000f0ee3c9caaaad87f31f2911a8909e767fb93948ea9395a5df554efbe8ef4cc01872c272a84e28a9e58')
ciphertexts.append('4721e27fac2293f08266a4e6f93e5aea3d8e48e6e836d3a7aaca633bf9d55f891de378b2899bcbe0244f55fe00e5aed3a1d744c42b3734c0a0889e43')
ciphertexts.append('0269f07fe93e91f1952caaa3f63e5cb36a9159a3ed3681abaaca7e2ce49016ce0be869fe98d3cca53e405fe800f6a9dcb5d5519d7c723288a79dd15c')
ciphertexts.append('0926f32dfe2f84f69b2da4f7e73e08e0789754e6f43096eefadf653af29116dc1ee973b2908a8eb7254b4cf848e6a394a2cc42902a3f68c0b18c940c')
ciphertexts.append('1e2ce67fff6a82f8833caaa3f8334dfd3d8d48e6e3739bafee9e7020f99c45c10be23de69596c7b2774d57f546e6b4c7bdca4fc863262e85e2809e4b')
ciphertexts.append('062da92de56a86f19f3de3ebfb7b00f572964ceae93bd3b9f8db622affd41f891aee7ce6dd9adae03a475ff354a3a5d1f4cc4fc42e2b6690ad93945e')
ciphertexts.append('1369f064f822d2fc9c21fee2ed3e5cfb31d941f1e8329da9efda363dff9442890dea78e08b92c2e0244657ee4ce7e7debbcc4fc42e376681b6c48258')

alpha = ['!', ' ', '(', ')', ',', '.', ':', '?', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

#def hex_To_String(hex1):
   # return bytes.fromhex(hex1[2:]).decode('utf-8')

def xor_Two_Str(str1, str2):
    return hex(int(str1,16) ^ int(str2,16))[2:]

def hexToASCII(hex):
    # initialize the ASCII code string as empty.
    ascii = ""
 
    for i in range(0, len(hex), 2):
 
        # extract two characters from hex string
        part = hex[i : i + 2]
 
        # change it into base 16 and
        # typecast as the character 
        ch = chr(int(part, 16))
 
        # add this char to final ASCII string
        ascii += ch
    return ascii


def string_To_Hex(string1):
    return (string1.encode('utf-8').hex()[2:])

#xors two hexes at a position specified
def xor_At_Position(cipher, word, pos):
    first = cipher[:pos]
    second = cipher[pos:pos+len(word)]
    second = xor_Two_Str(second, word) #checking the word xord at the position
    third = cipher[pos+len(word):]
    
    #just returning the xord part
    return second 



def cribDrag_Decryption(ciphertexts, guessedWord):
    key=''

    guessedWord = string_To_Hex(guessedWord)
 
    xordCiphers=[]
    for x in range(len(ciphertexts)-2):
        xordCiphers.append(xor_Two_Str(ciphertexts[0], ciphertexts[x+1]))
   
    # Now going to xor the hex guessed word at each position of the possible positions in each xord' ciphertext
    guessRange=len(ciphertexts[0]) - len(guessedWord)
    #for z in range (len(xordCiphers)):
    for x in range (guessRange):  
        temp = xor_At_Position(xordCiphers[0], guessedWord, x)
        nonalpha= False
        for char in hexToASCII(temp):
            if ((char in alpha) != True):
                nonalpha=True
        #only printing values that are within my alphabet - which was given
        if (nonalpha == False):
            print(f'{0}:{x}: {hexToASCII(temp)}')
        nonalpha=False

    return key





def main():
    guessedWord = ' the '
    key = cribDrag_Decryption(ciphertexts, guessedWord)
    #print(f'Key is: {key}')
    
    #for cipher in ciphertexts:
        #decrypted = xor_Two_Str(cipher, key)
        #print(f'Decrypted: {decrypted}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()```

Sample output:
0:0: 4xb!
0:8: 1tya
0:12: zg,c
0:18: wtfq
0:20: fwf2
0:24: e4,c
0:32: j12v
0:46: fqnz
0:56: hh1c
0:58: z th
0:70: k6eo
0:74: fics
0:80: g1wy
0:88: 88i?
0:92: j93v
````

Answer (score 1):

Who says that there is a repeated word? It seems more logical that the ciphertexts lines themselves are using a repeated key stream. Appending the lines is not a good idea, put them in a list instead.

Note that modern ciphertext, and certainly OTP generated ciphertext is considered *binary*. The hexadecimals are only for human consumption. So operate on bytes internally, not hexadecimals (or strings in general).

It is lucky that all the ciphertexts have the same size; it might well be that one was longer than the other in which case you would not be able to decrypt the final part.

---

First you'll need a frequency table for English text, preferably one that includes frequencies for ASCII text that includes frequencies of common symbols especially the space character.

Now try and construct the key stream for each byte index, assuming ASCII.

1. Go through all 256 byte values for the key (don't assume ASCII for the key)!
2. Get the ciphertext byte at the same index in each line and compute the corresponding plaintext byte.
3. (Optional) check if it falls within printable ASCII (+ tab & newline characters), if not you can probably skip the key value.
4. Otherwise calculate the average frequency of all the plaintext characters.

The key with the highest average is probably the correct one, although you may want to keep a set of close calls, I had to guess some characters and adjust the key values for those (easily calculated of course).

In case it is not clear I did manage to retrieve the text using this method.

---

One trick you can do is to take the square root of the frequency when calculating the average to compare; I find that otherwise the highly frequent characters such as space and `e` have too much bearing on the result. This fixed 2 out of 5 key values that were off for me.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I changed all of my hex manipulation to do so with binary, as that makes alot of sense, I believe I already implemented the second point there - as in my second for loop, I check if the current 'crib-drag' contains chars outside of my alphabet, if so I don't print it. Unfortunately after making that change I'm still receiving nothing english, I've tried about 20-30 different words.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer. The result you should get is high in Gutenberg content,  partial sentences / initial words and weird casing, some special characters such as parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

looks like your on the right track, but you need to perform a frequency analysis on the key for each position to find the key size, and then it should be relatively easy from there.

In terms of your output, print out all of the xord ciphertexts with the guessed word at each position simultaneously, whenever there's an identical 5 letter chunk, that means ' the ' exist at that spot.

Let me know if theres anything else.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding, I think you might have gotten confused with a vigenere cipher, as the key for a x time pad is the same length as the cipher. I also checked some other posts and I believe the method for using whitespace won't work, I checked the xord ciphertexts (i.e c1 xor c2, c3 xor c4, etc), and there was only 2 42==spaces.